# Setting only certain li elements to display inline

Tags: css

I have two unordered lists on a webpage that I am trying to design. I want one of them to display the elements inline, and the other to stay in the bullet points format. This is because the first one is for my navigation bar, and my second one is for an actual list.

This is more of a theoretical question. I am wondering how in general I can select only one of those two unordered lists to be displayed inline. In particular, since I would do this by writing

```
li{display: inline;}
```

I'm not sure how to have that directed towards only one list rather than both by using classes/ids.

Comment: You would typically use either a unique ID, class, combination, or specific selector to style elements differently. Read up on some basic CSS tutorials and you'll see how to select elements in a variety of ways

Comment: Have you tried giving the two `<li>` elements a selector? For example, `<li class="list-one">` and then style them accordingly with CSS?

Comment: if you used a nav tag, you could do `nav li {display:inline;}`  You can start from here if you are a total CSS beginer : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a class on one of them

```
<ul>
  <li>element 1</li>
  <li>element 2</li>
  <li>element 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="inlne">
  <li>element 4</li>
  <li>element 5</li>
  <li>element 6</li>
</ul>
```

with the CSS:

```
ul.inlne li {
  display: inline;
}
```

Only the `li` tags inside the `ul` tag with the mentioned class will be displalyed inline now. The first `ul` block will be displayed the common way as it is missing the inlne class.

Here you can see the results: https://jsfiddle.net/hpea9urj/1/